# AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have these tables tables:

```
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Voteinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'voteinfo'
    thing_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'), primary_key=True)
    thing = relationship('Thing', backref='voteinfo')
    upvotes = Column(Integer)
    downvotes = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, thing)
        self.thing = thing

class VoteThing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'votething'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    voter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('voter.id'))
    voter = relationship('Voter', backref='votescast')
    thing_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'))
    thing = relationship('Thing', backref='votesreceived')
    value = Column(Boolean)

    def __init__(self, voter, thing, value):
        if value is True:
            thing.voteinfo.upvotes += 1
        else:
            thing.voteinfo.downvotes += 1
```

When I try to run this, I get this error code in the "if value is True" clause:

```
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'upvotes'
```

I've tried giving Voteinfo its own unique ID and adding uselist=False to the relationship. I've tried replacing the relationship to thing from VoteThing to Voteinfo, but that didn't help either. I don't know what an InstrumentedList is. What is going on?

Comment: since `thing` is a parameter to `__init__`, presumably you're passing it when you instantiate the VoteThing. So what are you passing?

Comment: Yes, I am passing a thing:

thing1 = Thing(), 
user1 = User(), 
voteinfo1 = Voteinfo(thing1), 
votething1 = VoteThing(user1, thing1, True)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, here : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one, you have to add uselist=False not to the relationship, but to the backref.

```
thing = relationship('Thing', backref=backref('voteinfo', uselist=False))
```

Comment: For those of you reading this helpful answer from The Future, backref() is now a legacy feature: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/backref.html. Looks like uselist goes on the "many" side of the relationship marker: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#setting-uselist-false-for-non-annotated-configurations

Comment: Careful here, using `uselist=False` when a collection is expected will most likely result in unexpected behavior. I.e. it may seem to work ok but really it provides a single item rather than the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

It may been useful to add lazy='dynamic' argument to request that the query is not automatically executed and of course refresh (`thing = relationship('Thing', backref='voteinfo', lazy='dynamic')`), otherwise expression is issued internally call all() to return the list of 'thing' hence AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute error!!

Answer (score 0):

crazy how things have changed but this helped a ton!, an error raised when i used lazy = 'dynamic' but this is what my code looks like

`tool = db.relationship("Tool", backref="activities", uselist=False)`

it gives me db.model type and it's what i was looking for. Instead of a instrumented class list type.